# Overloading operators for template classes on the heap

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, operator-overloading, heap-memory

I am writing a template class. When I make a version of my class on the stack all the overloaded operators work just as expected. However when I declare the object on the heap none of the overloaded operators work.

in the header file I have:

```
template <typename K, typename V>
class KeyValue
{
private:
    K key;
    V value;
public:
    KeyValue(K, V);
    virtual ~KeyValue();
    bool operator==(KeyValue<K,V>& rhs)const;
    bool operator!=(KeyValue<K,V>& rhs)const;   
    bool operator<(const KeyValue<K,V>& rhs)const;
    bool operator>(const KeyValue<K,V>& rhs)const;
    KeyValue<K,V>* operator++();
    template <typename k, typename v>
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const KeyValue<k,v>& kv);
}
```

How they are implemented:

```
template <typename K, typename V>
bool KeyValue<K,V>::operator==(KeyValue<K,V>& rhs)const
{

    if (key == rhs.key)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

template <typename K, typename V>
bool KeyValue<K,V>::operator!=(KeyValue<K,V>& rhs)const
{
    if (key != rhs.key)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

template <typename K, typename V>
bool KeyValue<K,V>::operator<(const KeyValue<K,V>& rhs)const
{
    if (key < rhs.key)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

template <typename K, typename V>
bool KeyValue<K,V>::operator>(const KeyValue<K,V>& rhs)const
{

    if (key > rhs.key)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;   
}

template <typename k, typename v>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const KeyValue<k,v>& kv)
{
    os << kv->key << " " << kv->value;
    return os;
}

template <typename K, typename V>
KeyValue<K,V>* KeyValue<K,V>::operator++()
{
    ++value;
    return *this;
}
```

When I declare this class on the heap everything works how it should, however; If I declare this on the heap like:

```
KeyValue<string, int> *kv = new KeyValue<string, int>("test", 5);
```

And then try to increment kv it does nothing. Or if I try to print kv using `<<` operator it just prints off the memory address. I'm new to c++ so I am sure I am doing something wrong I just don't know what. Thank you for any help.

Comment: You have to dereference kv first. `(*kv)++` or `cout << *kv;` for instance.

Comment: By *increment `kv`*, if you mean `++kv`, then of course that is wrong. You are incrementing the pointer. You need to use `++(*kv)` to use the `operator++` function of the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared the class as `KeyValue<string, int> *kv`.

The asterisk here indicates that you are declaring a pointer.

What this means is that you are declaring that the variable `kv` points to a `KeyValue` object. When you print `kv` it prints the address of the `KeyValue` object that it points to.

In this case you use the `new` keyword which returns a pointer. For that reason you'll need the asterisk and to access the object itself you need to dereference the pointer first (as [john](https://stackoverflow.com/users/882003/john) said both `(*kv)++` and `cout << *kv` should work).

You can read over the use of pointers and how they work here: [Pointers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/89e4h321.aspx)

Alternatively, don't use a pointer.